# Authorization has been denied for this request using jwt everytime

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, jwt, asp.net-identity-2

I have Asp.Net Web App that work as Authorization server with url: http://localhost:46947/ and in it i create CustomJwtFormat.cs:

```
  public class CustomJwtFormat : ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>
    {

        private readonly string _issuer = string.Empty;

        public CustomJwtFormat(string issuer)
        {
            _issuer = issuer;
        }

        public string Protect(AuthenticationTicket data)
        {
            if (data == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
            }

            string audienceId = "d7f620e1-766b-4eda-b235-18bff11ceec8";

            string secKeyPlain = "7ca47d80-06b1-4c14-94c1-e3d9da83ef2a";

            string secKeyBase64 = Base64Encode(secKeyPlain);


            var secKey = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(secKeyPlain));

            var signingKey = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials(secKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);

            var issued = data.Properties.IssuedUtc;

            var expires = data.Properties.ExpiresUtc;

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_issuer, audienceId, data.Identity.Claims, issued.Value.UtcDateTime, expires.Value.UtcDateTime, signingKey);

            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            var jwt = handler.WriteToken(token);

            return jwt;
        }

        public AuthenticationTicket Unprotect(string protectedText)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private static string Base64Encode(string plainText)
        {
            var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
            return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
        }
    }
```

And In the Startup ConfigureAuth i add the CustomJwt:

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

        public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }

        // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
            PublicClientId = "self";
            OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
                Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
                AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
                // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                AccessTokenFormat = new CustomJwtFormat("http://localhost:46947")
            };

            // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
            app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);


        }


    }
```

And i have another WebApp with URL: http://localhost:43678/ which have some resources i want to protect. In his Startup.cs i called the below method before the WebApi midlleware:

```
public void ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            var issuer = "http://localhost:46947";
            string audienceId = "d7f620e1-766b-4eda-b235-18bff11ceec8";
            string audienceSecret = "7ca47d80-06b1-4c14-94c1-e3d9da83ef2a";
            string audienceSecretBase64 = Base64Encode(audienceSecret);

            // Api controllers with an [Authorize] attribute will be validated with JWT
            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
                new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                    AllowedAudiences = new[] { audienceId },
                    IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
                    {
                        new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, audienceSecretBase64)
                    }
                });
        }
```

No i can gain Jwt access token by calling this endpoint:

http://localhost:46947/token with Post verb, username, password and grant_type as password.

When i take the accesstoken and try to get any protected resource from the resource app like this:
GET: http://localhost:43678/api/books

Authorization: Bearer x.y.z

every time it's return:

```
  "Message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."
```

I want to mention that i try to validate the jwt token via [jwt debugger](https://jwt.io/#debugger) but every time it return invalid even when i put my secretkey

Example:
[image: JWT Debugging]

Comment: Hi @marzouk looking at the attached image, I believe the audience Id should "d7f620e1-766b-4eda-b235-18bff11ceec8" not "appId". From where you get the "appId"?

Comment: @marzouk was this issue ever resolved?

Comment: I think it was because of some wrong info in my payload .. If you have the same issue try to review every key and value most probably it's a wrong info

Comment: @Marzouk what was the wrong info? Been at this for a little over a day started with a clean build same error. I am able to get the tokens but whenever I put it in the header to get protected endpoints it doesn't work

Comment: @Marzouk The issuer for the TokenConsumer method is different from my localhost would that cause any problems?